# Php file_get_contents

Tags: php

Добрый день, нарисовалась проблемка,есть

фаил **menu.php** в нем php код

```
echo"1";
```

Фаил **index.php** в нем:

```
$templete_site=file_get_contents('template.php');
while ($row_templete=mysql_fetch_array($res_templete)) {
$templete_site=str_replace("{".$row_templete[name_variables]."}", "$row_templete[php_variables]", "$templete_site");}
echo $templete_site;
```

Фаил **template.php** в нем html код со вставками php вставки php не работают

в файле **template.php**

```
....
<div id="telefon">(4852) {telefon}</div>
        <div id="header_menu">
        <a href=""><img src="{site_full}images/menu_home.png" width="44" height="46" border="0"></a>
            <div id="header_menu_all">
            <?include('menu_top.php');?><a href="">Главная</a>
            <a href="">О нас</a>
            <a href="">Контакты</a>
            </div>
        </div>
.....
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтоб все работало чтоб работали замены ( `{site_full}` ) и php вставки тоже...
заранее спс

Answer (score 1):

```
$templete_site = str_replace(
     "{".$row_templete['name_variables']."}",
     $row_templete['php_variables'],
     $templete_site
);
```

Уберите кавычки с второго и третьего параметров.

Answer (score -2):

ну сделайте eval вместо echo но реально так никто не делает. Если вставки то вставки, если php то тогда зачем вам шаблонизатор?